# Using an Array to store accumulated number

Tags: php, arrays

I created a for(...) cycle where I plan to go through the values of an array and use those values to accumulate them in another array, but I'm getting a notice from Apache that says **Notice: Undefined offset: ...**. The code I'm using is something like this:

```
for ($a=0;$a<count($original_array);$a++){
    $accumulate_array[$a] += $original_array[$a]
}
```

I think the notice comes from the part where I do the "+=" because it's doing something like:

```
$accumulate_array[$a] = $accumulate_array[$a] + $original_array[$a]
```

And it's referencing a value that still doesn't exist, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, the notice is because of this line:

```
$accumulate_array[$a] += $original_array[$a];
```

Because it expands to:

```
$accumulate_array[$a] = $accumulate_array[$a] + $original_array[$a];
```

And `$accumulate_array[$a]` is undefined, while it's trying to grab that value. So, if you're creating a running sum, you probably want to initialize it to zero, like so:

```
if( !isset( $accumulate_array[$a] )) $accumulate_array[$a] = 0;
$accumulate_array[$a] = $accumulate_array[$a] + $original_array[$a];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done, you must declare your table before using it:

```
$accumulate_array = array();
```

Comment: This isn't the source of the OP's problems, PHP will just create the array when it's first referenced [without any warning or notice](http://viper-7.com/qJbgJi).

Answer (score 0):

First, declare the new (empty) array:

```
$accumulate_array = array();
```

Then, push as needed:

```
for ($a=0; $a<count($original_array); $a++){
    array_push($accumulate_array, $original_array[$a]); 
}
```

Comment: The desired functionality is to add values, this does no addition.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add check for not existing index. And, why don't you use `foreach` for array iteration?

```
foreach($original_array as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($accumulate_array[$key])) {
        $accumulate_array[$key] += $original_array[$key];
    } else {
        $accumulate_array[$key] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach`. It's seems that your array's indexes are not sequential/integer keys.